# using gen.task with Tornado for a simple function

Tags: python, asynchronous, web, tornado

Just trying to use the async functions of Tornado - I want to invoke a method from my handler but it keeps telling me that it "got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'".

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        response = yield gen.Task(self.dosomething, 'argument')
        self.write(response)
        self.finish()

    def dosomething(self, myargument):
        pass
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Non-blocking function requires callback, where it pass result.

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        response = yield gen.Task(self.dosomething, 'argument')
        self.write(response)
        self.finish()

    def dosomething(self, myargument, callback):
        return callback(myargument)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish the error message would indicate it was missing, not that it found a 'callback'. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi, I'd like to know how you actually made dosomething acting as non-blocking? Did you implement any threading/other mechanism so that it does not block?