# Tornado async call to a function

Tags: python, class, function, asynchronous, tornado

I am making a web application using Python + Tornado which basically serves files to users. I have no database.

The files are either directly picked up and served if they are available, or generated on the fly if not.

I want the clients to be served in an async manner, because some files may already be available, while others need to be generated (thus they need to wait, and I don't want them to block other users).

I have a class that manages the picking or generation of files, and I just need to call it from Tornado.

What is the best way (most efficient on CPU and RAM) to achieve that? Should I use a thread? A sub process? A simple [gen.Task like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679040/using-gen-task-with-tornado-for-a-simple-function)?

Also, I would like my implementation to work on Google App Engines (I think they do not allow sub processes to be spawned?).

I'm relatively new to the async web servicing, so any help is welcome.

Comment: The gen.Task will work fine. If your file getting/generating code cannot play nicely in that then a thread will work fine. You can also spawn multiple processes, but I do not know the limitations on the Google App Engine.

Comment: Thank's for the reply. Do you also know how it will work out if I spawn multiple gen.Task? I mean, my **instance method** can be quite CPU and time consuming, if this method is called several times from multiple users, what will happen? Will all the methods run async in parallel or will the next methods wait for the previous ones to terminate first? (note that I have a single instance of my class that I use throughout my whole application)

Comment: Totally blanked, it should be fine, but regardless of your solution it would become an issue with a lot of threads regardless. If this is a worry try looking into splitting into separate processes or running multiple instances behind a load balance.

Comment: Thank's a lot Sean for the answer. Yes indeed I will make a load balancer application in the background that will run CPU heavy tasks in the background, thus users will always have the files available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found the answers to my questions: The genTask example is indeed the best way to implement an async call, and it is due to the fact that the example does use a **Python coroutine**, which I didn't understand at first glance because I thought **yield** was only used to return a value for generators.

Concrete example:

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        response = yield gen.Task(self.dosomething, 'argument')
```

What is important here is the combination of two things:

- **yield** , which in fact spawns a coroutine (or pseudo-thread, which is very efficient and are done to be highly concurrent-friendly).
  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/
- `gen.Task()` which is a non-blocking (async) function, because if you spawn a coroutine on a blocking function, it won't be async. `gen.Task()` is provided by Tornado, specifically to work with the coroutine syntax of Python. More infos:
  http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html

So a canonical example of an async call in Python using coroutines:

```
response = yield non_blocking_func(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Also here is another post where are detailed both the coroutine and old callback implementation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812715/using-a-simple-python-generator-as-a-co-routine-in-a-tornado-async-handler?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Now [Documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html#examples) have solution.

Simple example:

```
import os.path
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen

class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, filename):
        result = yield self.some_usefull_process(filename)
        self.write(result)

    @gen.coroutine
    def some_usefull_process(self, filename):
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            status = yield self.generate_file(filename)
            result = 'File created'
        else:
            result = 'File exists'

        raise gen.Return(result)

    @gen.coroutine
    def generate_file(self, filename):
        fd = open(filename, 'w')
        fd.write('created')
        fd.close()
```