# Iterating a loop using await or yield causes error

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, tornado, coroutine

I come from the land of `Twisted`/[`Klein`](https://github.com/twisted/klein). I come in peace and to ask for `Tornado` help.  I'm investigating Tornado and how its take on async differs from Twisted.  Twisted has something similar to `gen.coroutine` which is [`defer.inlineCallbacks`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html#inline-callbacks-using-yield) and I'm able to write async code like this:

*kleinsample.py*

```
@app.route('/endpoint/<int:n>')
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def myRoute(request, n):
    jsonlist = []
    for i in range(n):
        yield jsonlist.append({'id': i})
    return json.dumps(jsonlist)
```

curl cmd:

```
curl localhost:9000/json/2000
```

This endpoint will create a JSON string with `n` number of elements.  `n` can be small or very big.  I'm able to break it up in Twisted such that the event loop won't block using `yield`.  Now here's how I tried to convert this into Tornado:

*tornadosample.py*

```
async def get(self, n):
    jsonlist = []
    for i in range(n):
        await gen.Task(jsonlist.append, {'id': i})    # exception here
    self.write(json.dumps(jsonlist))
```

The traceback:

```
 TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments
```

I'm confused about what I'm supposed to do to properly iterate each element in the loop so that the event loop doesn't get blocked.  Does anyone know the "Tornado" way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot and must not await `append`, since it isn't a coroutine and doesn't return a Future. If you want to occasionally yield to allow other coroutines to proceed using Tornado's event loop, await [gen.moment](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.moment).

```
from tornado import gen

async def get(self, n):
    jsonlist = []
    for i in range(n):
        jsonlist.append({'id': i})
        if not i % 1000:  # Yield control for a moment every 1k ops
           await gen.moment
    return json.dumps(jsonlist)
```

That said, unless this function is *extremely* CPU-intensive and requires hundreds of milliseconds or more to complete, you're probably better off just doing all your computation at once instead of taking multiple trips through the event loop before your function returns.

Comment: I planned to do something similar to your answer (something like ``await Future()`` then do the appending). Hoping to find a better solution, if not your answer will have to do. It's not CPU intensive but the actual code (which is significantly more complex than the example in my post) is a section that blocks just enough to disrupt other functionality in my current synchronous site.  Hence my desire to *pause* iterating for a *moment* (all puns intended).

Comment: What would constitute a "better solution" than what I posted? What can I help you with?

Comment: Sorry didn't mean your answer wasn't a good answer. I could've sworn the last time I used Tornado there was a function which allowed me to pass an iterable or generator then fire off callbacks per element asynchronously. Twisted has something called a Cooperator which can do something similar so I figured Tornado had a similar solution. Your solution should be fine for my requirements

Comment: ah hah! I figured out who you are ``A. Jesse Jiryu Davis``! :D I recently saw your video from PyCon.

Answer (score 1):

`list.append()` returns `None`, so it's a little misleading that your Klein sample looks like it's yielding some object. This is equivalent to `jsonlist.append(...); yield` as two separate statements. The tornado equivalent would be to do `await gen.moment` in place of the bare `yield`.

Also note that in Tornado, handlers produce their responses by calling `self.write()`, not by returning values, so the `return` statement should be `self.write(json.dumps(jsonlist))`.

Comment: Yeah I can see why it's misleading. It's not the best snippet in the world, but it got my point across (at least I thought). I forgot to change ``return`` to ``self.write`` since I wrote the example on the fly. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at `gen.Task` [docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.Task):

> Adapts a callback-based asynchronous function for use in coroutines.
>
> Takes a function (and optional additional arguments) and runs it with those arguments **plus a callback keyword argument**. The argument passed to the callback is returned as the result of the yield expression.

Since `append` doesn't accept a keyword argument it doesn't know what to do with that `callback` kwarg and spits that exception.

What you could do is wrap `append` with your own function that does accept a `callback` kwarg or the approach showed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11683014/1453822) answer.